# UIButton gradient not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, uibutton

I found this code from tutorial and tried to use it:

```
CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
btnGradient.frame = button.bounds;
btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                      (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                      nil];
[button.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];
```

The code is in viewDidLoad method.

button is defined like this in .h file: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button;`

and it's @synthesized in .m file and it's connected in interface builder

I am able to do other customization to the button like changing its background color (solid color) and changing the color of text. But when I try to use gradient color the background is just transparent.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably first you need to set the frame button. Try this.

```
+ (UIButton*) buttonWithGradient:(CGSize)size beginColor:(UIColor*)beginColor endColor:(UIColor*)endColor
{
    CGRect frame = { CGPointZero, size };

    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    CAGradientLayer* gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = frame;
    gradient.colors = @[(id)beginColor.CGColor, (id)endColor.CGColor];
    [button.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    return [button autorelease];
}
```

Comment: How can I use that? (I'm not very familiar with obj-c/cocoa)

Comment: rewrite + (UIButton*) buttonWith... -> - (UIButton*) buttonWith... and in the your class: UIButton *button = [self buttonWithGradient:"your size" beginColor:"your begin color" endColor:"your end color"];

Comment: Method start with + static method.

Comment: I made the whole button programmatically and used your method and now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the gradient layer's frame to cover the entire button. Chance is that at `viewDidLoad` the button's size is zero, which makes the gradient layer's frame zero... And later when the button's size changes, the gradient layer's frame doesn't changed accordingly.

Subclassing `UIButton` and overriding `layoutSubviews` is a good idea

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton {

}

@implementation MyButton {
    CAGradientLayer* _gradient;
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    _gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    _gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                      (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                      nil];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradient atIndex:0];
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

     _gradient.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

Another option is to use `observeValueForKeyPath...` to detect changes in the button's frame, and resize the layer accordingly. Not a very reusable solution thought.

Comment: [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradient atIndex:0]; was the solution I was looking for. MUCH THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem where the gradient wasn't appearing. Like @khanhnguyen said the problem was I setting it in viewDidLoad and because of that the button's bounds was unknown so nothing was appearing.

When I moved the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it appeared. Here is the answer in Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let purpleColor = UIColor(red: 129/255, green: 52/255, blue: 175/255, alpha: 1)
    let pinkColor = UIColor(red: 221/255, green: 42/255, blue: 123/255, alpha: 1)
    let yellowColor = UIColor(red: 254/255, green: 218/255, blue: 119/255, alpha: 1)

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradientLayer.frame = yourButton.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [purpleColor.cgColor, pinkColor.cgColor, yellowColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)

    yourButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

If using a collection view cell add it to:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
}
```